# How do I access subscription name and resource group name from inside my Logic App?

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I have a logic app that so far is working as expected. I received some feedback that the log messages could be improved by including the subscription name and resource group name. Where can I access these properties? I checked the dynamic variables and looked around in the expressions but I don't see anything that resembles these properties.

I found the accepted answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58020918) post. However, the id I get - in the form "/workflows/dd1d---omitted---52bc" - looks to be a workflow id and doesn't contain the properties I usually see in a resource id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the common behaviour seen when using the trigger `When a HTTP request is received` to get the worflow triggered. So, in that case you will receive workflow id in `/workflows/e0*******bbd` format. While if you use other triggers such as `Recurrence` you will receive in the format that you required.

[image]

**Result:**

[image]

[image]

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Like SwethaKandikonda said, this goes weird when using a `http-trigger`. There is a work-around, however. When you set-up concurrency control on your http-trigger, you will get the `workflow().id` with the correct `subscription-id` and `resource-group-name`.

[concurrency-control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3EJW.png)